# Why does the function f(|x|) look like this?

Tags: functions

If the image is f(x), why does f(|x|) look like two triangles above the x axis (basically the right side duplicated on the left)?

[image: function image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let us call $g(x)=f(|x|)$. You agree that $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\geq 0$, so the graph remains unchanged.

What happens when you try to calculate say $g(-1)$?. You get $f(|-1|)=f(1)=2$, it is the same for all $x$ values that are negative, so that is why you get a copy of the triangle.

Comment: Can you add a generalization so that the answer is complete?

Answer (score 0):

$f(|x|)$ will equal $f(x)$ if $x$ is positive, and $f(-x)$ otherwise. Therefore, the positive part of graph of $f(|x|)$ will be identical to the positive part of the graph of $f(x)$, and the negative part will be a reflection of the positive part of the graph of $f(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I think I should have put it in a better way like the other answers. Let $g(x)=f(|x|)$ and now $g(x)$ will look like the positive part of $f(x)$ flipped if $x<0$ since $$g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} f(x) & x\geq0 \\ f(-x) & x<0\end{array}\right.$$
Now, $g(-2)=f(2)$ and so forth.

Comment: Nothing in the problem guarantees that $f(-2)=f(2)$.

Comment: @Did Thank you for pointing the error out. Edited for better clarity.